# Setting DataSource of DevEx xtra GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Initially my DevEx xtra GridControl's **mainView  has a Column** with field F1.
(I had used reflection to add a column to the mainview .)

Now at runtime ,i want to change the dataSource. **The new dataSource has a field F1**.
How do i make sure that only those fileds are shown which were added by me earlier.
I dont want all the fields of datasource to be shown in the gridControl.

Comment: Could you show some code, like how you're changing the dataSource?

Comment: well i m using reflection to set the dataSource ..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Changing to a data source with more fields doesn't populate more columns (unless I do it explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Call `gridView.PopulateColumns()`.